# How to check whether a string contains every letter in the alphabet in C++

Tags: c++

I wanted to write a C++ program that checks whether a string contains every letter in the alphabet from a to z.

Comment: I don't ! Any attempt ?

Comment: Use the std::string class (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) and give it a shot. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
bool allLetters(string s) {
    vector<bool> checked(255, false);
    for (int i=0; i < int(s.size()); ++i)
        checked[s[i]] = true;
    for (int i='a'; i <= 'z'; ++i)
        if (!checked[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should put the character range in question as additional parameters to the function, to make it more general (as you are already gathering the information for all possible character values).

Comment: Yeah, of course you can generalize it.. (I'm aware that there are different cultures that use different alphabets), but the idea I think remains the same.

Comment: For what it's worth, the standard doesn't guarantee that `'a'` ... `'z'` is a contiguous range. It is in ASCII but not in EBCDIC. So your code would reject `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` on an implementation that used EBCDIC (if you could find one), because it doesn't contain the unused code point `138 == ('i' + 1)` or the character '`±' == ('j' - 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a character set where the letters are contiguous from a to z:

```
bool contains_all_letters(const char * p)
{
    unsigned seen = 0;
    while (*p)
    {
        unsigned c = *p++ - 'a';
        if (c < 26)
        {
            seen |= (1 << c);
        }
    }
    return seen == (1 << 26) - 1;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick:  You need to account for upper and lower case.  Also, the variable `c` will have underflow if any character less than `a` is entered. :-(

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize the first statement was exact.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews For characters lower than `a`, the subtraction will yield a negative result, which will be converted into a huge unsigned result, which will definitely not be less than 26 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this (in ASCII)

```
bool has_alphabet(std::string const &s)
{
    std::bitset<26> alphabet;
    for (char c : s) {
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            alphabet.set(c - 'A');
        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            alphabet.set(c - 'a');
    }
    return 26 == alphabet.count();
}
```

You need to include the `bitset` header and no matter whether caps are before or after lower letters or they have other symbols between them, this will work